# iOS - get NSMutableArray from another class

Tags: ios, delegates, global-variables

I have an NSMutableArray defined in one view controller, and I want to access it in another view controller.
Should I use a delegate or somehow make this array global?
Is there a way to make this array global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `NSMutableArray` `Class` follow below code:

DataArray.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DataArray : NSMutableArray

+(NSMutableArray *)sharedInstance ;

@end
```

DataArray.m file

```
#import "DataArray.h"

static  NSMutableArray *_sharedInstance ;

@implementation DataArray

+(NSMutableArray *)sharedInstance {

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        if (_sharedInstance  == nil) {
            _sharedInstance = [NSMutableArray  new];
        }
    });
    return _sharedInstance ;
}

@end
```

This way DataArray will be a shared NSMutableArray that can be accessed from everywhere.
To access it you just need to call [DataArray sharedInstance]. To that you can add any kind of NSMutableArray method.

Comment: You call the any view controller [DataArray sharedInstance]addObject:object]; like this array all properties is working in add the element , deleting everything

Comment: Thanks for the help! It works. I now can access this kind of array from everywhere.